# Openerp - How to set default value for fields.binary?

Tags: odoo

Anyone now how to set default value for fields.binary ?

I succeed to put data in the fields.binary with the default_get() method, but when I try to open the file (by clicking 'Save As' button), I get this error message :

> Firefox cannot find the file at the address http://172.17.0.2:8061/openerp/form/save_binary_data?_terp_field=template_file&_terp_model=import_batch_number&_terp_id=F

Comment: please put the your code so we can understand very weal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue because the displayed record is not yet saved in DB, so OpenERP cannot get the document stored in fields.binary.

I created the document before open the view and it's work well.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this code

```
import base64

binary_field=fields.Binary(string='Image',default='get_default_image')

def get_default_image(self):
   with open("yourfile_path.ext", "rb") as image_file:
      self.binary_field = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
```

Hope this helps.